# Jenkins - git requests for login credentials using Git plugin

Tags: jenkins, keychain, devops

I have a couple of Jobs that pull code from bitbucket and build it in jenkins.
I'm using Git plugin to specify the repository URL + the git credentials.

Even though I set the credentials in each Job configuration, each time there is a push to bitbucket(that triggers the jenkins job), Mac is asking for "git-credential-osxkeychain wants to user the "login" keychain".
If I enter the password, the job will run and it will not ask again for a couple of hours.

I would like to make it permanent so that message won't be prompted any more.

Any advice ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, that only happens if you are using https URLs, as part of a [git credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials).
Using SSH URLs would bypass that entirely.

If the actual error message is

```
git-credential-osxkeychain wants to use your confidential information stored in "xxx" in your keychain.
```

Check out "[unable to click always allow on git-credential-osxkeychain popup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34281389/6309)": delete the bitbucket entry, and do a git ls-remote /url/bitbucket/repo to force the credential helper to ask those credentials again: enter them, *then* try your Jenkins jobs again.