# Permission denied when pushing file to remote

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-bash

I previously used git bash for local repository.
I have connected to a GitHub account and I always pushed my files without any problem.
Later, I have uninstall the bash and reinstall again with new user and email.  Now when I try to push the file to remote I got an error:

```
 Permission to SyedMiraj/SpringSecurityWithTicketBooking.git denied to biid-sua.
 unable to access 'https://github.com/SyedMiraj/SpringSecurityWithTicketBooking.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I have tried and created a new SSH key and add it in the remote repo.
But the problem is still existing and truly speaking I can't push anything to my remote.
My two GitHub accounts are biid-sua and smiraj.

How would you propose to restore GitHub pushes?

Answer (score 5):

A couple of points here:

- the user and email used to make commits have nothing to do with the remote repo (here hosted on GitHub) for authentication
- SSH keys (old or new) are *not* used at all when pushing to GitHub with an *https* URL.
  If it uses your first `biid-sua` account, this is because of a git credential helper, that has cached your `biid-sua` credentials for `github.com`.

You can either make sure and delete that entry ([either on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47967883/6309) or [on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47466980/6309)). You will be prompt for your new username/password at the next push.

Or you can swtich to an SSH URL:

```
cd /path/to/my/local/repo
git remote set-url origin g2:SyedMiraj/SpringSecurityWithTicketBooking.git
```

And then make sure your `~/.ssh/config` defines the `g2` entry and references the right key ([as I explain here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681936/6309))

```
#Account one
Host g1
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /c/Users/yourname/.ssh/id_rsa_biid-sua
    User git

#Account two
Host g2
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /c/Users/yourname/.ssh/id_rsa_smiraj
    User git
```

Assuming that you have name your SSH keys in HOME:

- `.ssh/id_rsa_biid-sua` and `.ssh/id_rsa_biid-sua.pub`
- `.ssh/id_rsa_smiraj` and `.ssh/id_rsa_smiraj.pub`

Comment: ~/.ssh/config , how to use this path on window?, where this config file should be created?

Comment: @KarthikKumar `~` will by default fall back to `%USERPROFILE%`. So you can create the config file as `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config`.

Answer (score -1):

you need to change your repo config on your PC to ssh way: [refer](http://you%20need%20to%20change%20your%20repo%20config%20on%20your%20PC%20to%20ssh%20way:)